# Why am I not notified of comments?

Tags: support, comment

User QiL responded in a comment to a previous comment I made about his answer to [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/still-torsion-free-after-nilredution).
To my knowledge I have not been advised, although he wrote @GeorgesElencwajg in  that comment.

Why is that?

1) Because my "about me" is blank? (stackexchange has my e-mail address, though)
2) Because there was no space between *@Georges* and *Elencwajg* ? However I think some users did put a blank when addressing me in their comments and I wasn't advised either.
3) Because I don't know where to look?
4) For some other reason?

(Apologies if this has already been asked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/161783) for the official info on the @ reply system.

Reason 1 is not correct; you will receive your notifications whenever you are logged in on an SE site (if you mean *email notification*, that is something you have to opt into; however the "about me" section does not affect this either).

Note that only the first three letters have to be a match; so reason 2 is definitely not it (in fact when typing an @ reply, the system provides you with a list of users in the comment thread, for convenience; all of its suggestions take the user name and strip the spaces).

Regarding reason 3: the notifications are displayed in the global inbox on the upper left corner of the site; a notification will look like

[image: global inbox]

(that is where you can set up your email notifications if you want).

So, as far as I can tell there should be no reason for you not to have been notified. However I do have a guess: seeing that QiL's comment was edited, perhaps the original comment had the @ reply in a situation where it would not work, and then it was edited to its current form; if the system doesn't know to recheck a comment for new notifications after an edit, you wouldn't have received one. But I don't know if that's what happened, or if that's how the system works.

Comment: Dear @Zev: thanks a lot for your swift answer, which completely solves my problem and as a bonus gives a lot of interesting  information on the way the site works. So the answer was reason 3): I didn't know where to look!  Now that I know where it is, I see that the  global inbox works perfectly and I just saw the test comment you  added  under QiL's answer.Fantastic!  All the best,

Comment: Actually that inbox is even more fabulous than I would have hoped: I can actually access 28 *pages* of comments to my past answers! Talk of a backlog! But I'm looking forward to catching up: comments are always quite interesting on our site (and I certainly don't  mean just  those related  to my answers)

Comment: @Georges: Very glad to help!